# How view return records

Tags: sql, database, view

I have sql view and I am getting values from view like this

select * from MyView where date > 'anydate'.

My question:
When this where clause will execute? Once all records return by view?

Comment: The execution plan for the query answers your question. Just get it and see.

Answer (score 0):

what you are actually doing is, you are telling the database to select some data from its record where date is greater than a particular date, so it will just do the it from the last command, I will only select datas where date is greater than a particular date

Comment: Then what if I have where condition in view also

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Views are a bit like Macros in some other languages - they're effectively a "fragment" you can insert into a larger query.

That larger query is optimized *as a whole*<sup>1</sup>. It doesn't matter which table references, predicates, etc came from any views versus those which were written explicitly in the submitted query text.

So if you have a `WHERE` clause inside the view and a `WHERE` clause you're applying when querying the view, both are considered equally. Neither is guaranteed to be evaluated before or after the other<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>Unless working with features where the view is *materialized*, in which case the view "result" data is being stored and updated separately from any queries against the view. Exact details vary between SQL database products for if they support such a feature, how they're maintained, etc.

<sup>2</sup>In line with the general principal that in SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. It's up to the optimizer to decide on the order in which operations take place, so long as it's logically consistent.

Comment: Totally agree with you but I have just converted that view into table-value function and passing parameter's to it. Now where clause is in view and performance is much better but I don't know why.

Comment: @Faisal - if you're talking SQL Server's Table-Valued Functions, there's an important different between Inline TVFs (which act like a view, as above, and optimized as part of the containing query) and Multi-Statement TVFs (which, well, aren't, and are optimized and run separately)